# ASP.NET MVC 3 Project published only works with all project files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, publish

I have been publishing my MVC3 project to IIS including "All Project Files", this has been working fine, but when I changed it to "Only files needed to run this application", the project published fine, but if I try and browse the site in IIS, I get this error.

> Parser Error  Description: An error
>   occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this
>   request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and
>   modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load
>   type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Control Language="C#"
>   Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl"
>   %>

I remember that I read something a while ago about issues with deploying web projects that only have files required to run it and that by including all source code it works.

I am including the .mvc, .routing, .abstraction dll's as copy local in project.

Has anybody else come across this issue? I cannot find anything on the web concerning this anymore.

Comment: Is MVC installed on the Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool,

I just found the answer and it worked, i added this bit of code to my web.config and its now working fine.

```
 <pages
      validateRequest="false"
      pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
      pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
      userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
```

could somebody please tell me why i had to do this.

regards,

p.

Comment: The default page parser for ASP.net does not understand the angle bracket generic syntax used in strongly typed views, so you need to use the parser from mvc, which can handle the generic type.

Comment: thanks tom, but do you know why it was not required if i dedployed all project files?